# How can i get enumerate object inside on screen

Tags: python, uppercase, enumerate

I want to write screen Capital letters and index numbers in word="WElCMMerC".For example [(0,W),(1,E),(3,C),(4,M),(5,M)...]

```
def cap(word):

    w=list(enumerate(i) for i in word if i!=i.lower())
    print (w)

print(cap("WElCMMerC"))
```

Comment: now i see on the screen  like this [<enumerate object at 0x000001A176231BD8>, <enumerate object at 0x000001A17634DDB8>

Answer (score 2):

You can loop over the result of `enumerate`, and keep only those which have an uppercase letter (using `isupper` to check for that), and return the list `w`, don't print inside the function:

```
def cap(word):
    w = [i for i in enumerate(word) if i[1].isupper()]
    return w

print(cap("WElCMMerC"))
```

Output:

```
[(0, 'W'), (1, 'E'), (3, 'C'), (4, 'M'), (5, 'M'), (8, 'C')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You made a list of `enumerate` objects.  Read the documentation: `enumerate` is an iterator, much like `range`.  Rather, you need to *use* the enumeration.

```
return [(idx, letter) 
        for idx, letter in enumerate(word)
            if letter.isupper()]
```

In English:

```
Return the pair of index and letter
for each index, letter pair in the word
    but only when the letter is upper-case.
```